# Android can i avoid onCreate() being called?

Tags: android, stack, android-activity

I have two applications App-1 & App-2. App-2 has a button which will start App-1.

The need is to behave like the following:-

1. User launches App-1 (using launcher) & activities A, B & C are started & activity C is at the top of the activity stack.
2. Please note that entry point of App-1 is activity A.
3. User presses home key.
4. User then launches the application App-2. User chooses the button in App-2 to start App-1.
5. `onClick()` of the button in App-2 has the following code:-

   Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setAction("com.x.y.z"); //resolves to activity A of App-1
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        i.putExtra("x", "y");
        startActivity(i);

After step-4, `onCreate()` of activity A is called which is quite normal. But I want Android to bring the entire Activity Stack to be brought to the foreground, since App-1 is running & Android hasn't killed it.(Which is the same behavior if I had launched App-1 after step-2).

I want activity C to be shown to the user.

Kindly help me if it is possible to do this.

I have tried making activity A as singleTask & singleInstance. if i do that, only activity A is brought to the foreground which is not what i want.

the snippet of App-1's manifest looks like below:-

```
<activity android:name=".aa.a"

         android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|locale"
         android:label="@string/app_name"
         android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay"
         >
            <intent-filter>
             <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
           </intent-filter>
           <intent-filter>
                 <action android:name="com.x.y.z" />
                 <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                 <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
             </intent-filter>

</activity>
```

Comment: NO. you cannot avoid onCreate() being called!! you need to find another way in your activity flow.

Comment: Thanks Ankit for the response. i hope you have read the post completely though i agree that its needs lot of patience & time. I think this is something not very difficult to do. developers may want this kind of behavior to minimize the amount of code to be written to imitate same behavior. I am not sure what is the difficulty in providing such an option (of course with certain understandable constraints).

Answer (score 1):

FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK informs Android to start a new task; the new task doesn't contain B & C, so don't expect any of them to be shown.
Also, FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP removes B & C, which is exactly opposite to what you want.

Try removing both flags.